# Mapbox showing black building tiles when color layer is added for android flutter works fine on Ios

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, flutter-mapbox-gl

This is what I can see on Console but fill color value I'm passing is already String:
**{my_package_name}[JNI]: Error setting property: fill-color [2]: Expected string but found number instead.**
I'm using mapbox in my flutter app, when I add color layer on the map, Instead of buildings getting colored into that color, they turn black. on IOS the buildings get colored with same function [here is how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1aeZ.png)

I tried to change the opacities & tried to even give color like "red" but still buildings get black color.